# overly patches which represent the significants points over contour map

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, contour, anova

I am trying to add hatching (like dots, hashes, .. ) over contour map. Such hatching could represent the only the statistically significant contours, or contours with certain criteria. Like the following image on nature article (second and third plot) http://www.nature.com/articles/srep16853/figures/3.

The following code show plot of precipitation from NOAA data [available](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/repository/entry/get/precip.mon.mean.nc?entryid=synth%3Ae570c8f9-ec09-4e89-93b4-babd5651e7a9%3AL21zdS9wcmVjaXAubW9uLm1lYW4ubmM%3D) for download at.

```
import numpy as np
import sys 
import netCDF4 as nc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as m 
import mpl_toolkits.basemap as bm
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '../');import py4met as sm;reload(sm)

#- Reading data for a timeslice, latitude, and longitude:
diri_output="./"
diri="./"
tmp_file = nc.Dataset(diri+"precip.mon.mean.nc","r")
print(tmp_file.variables)
p_pre   = tmp_file.variables['precip']
lat     = tmp_file.variables['lat'][:]
lon     = tmp_file.variables['lon'][:]
time    = tmp_file.variables['time']
tmp_file.close


lat1=np.min(lat)
lat2=np.max(lat)
lon1=np.min(lon)
lon2=np.max(lon)

[lonall, latall] = np.meshgrid(lon[:], lat[:])
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8+4, 6+4), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')    
mapproj = bm.Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=lat1, llcrnrlon=lon1,urcrnrlat=lat2, urcrnrlon=lon2,resolution='l')
mapproj.drawcoastlines()
mapproj.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
mapproj.drawcountries()
x, y = mapproj(lonall, latall)
plt.contourf(x,y,p_pre[240,:,:],cmap=plt.cm.GnBu)
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal',pad=0.05,shrink=0.6)
plt.title("title")
xx,yy=np.where(p_pre[240,:,:] >= 20)
sig=np.copy(p_pre[0,:,:])
sig[:,:]=1
sig[xx,yy]=0
#plt.contourf(x,y,sig,hatches=['.'])
plt.show()
```

I want to hatch all contours above 20 mm, so I used the above command

> plt.contourf(x,y,sig,hatches=['.'])

but it didn’t work (it make dotes everywhere on the map and not only contours with specific criteria), thus I commented it. 
Any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [matplotlib example page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_hatching.html) for a demo of how hatches can be used with `contourf`. Of particular relevance to your problem is that (1) there is a keyword `level` that `contourf` takes in order to establish the bounds of what values get colored and/or hatched and (2) an empty string `""` can be used for the absence of a hatch.

So, instead of the `plt.contourf` line you have commented out try

```
levels = [p_pre[240,:,:].min(), 20, p_pre[240,:,:].max()]
plt.contourf(x, y, p_pre[240,:,:], levels=levels, hatches=["", "."], alpha=0)
```

I had trouble recreating your plot from the data you linked to, so I generated some random data to make the image below using the same principles I describe above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me. Now, I understood the number of hatched used is the number of lines used -1, thus I can hatch different contours levels with different hatches. Thanks again.

Comment: I am happy that matplotlib has such capabilities, I searched for how do patching in MatLab and I didn't found such built in capabilities, rather I found the following contribution on MatLab file exchange [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30733-hatchfill).